# OSX: Determining if static libraries listed by brew are deletable?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I recently switched over to brew from using mac ports.  After grabbing up and installing all the brew versions of ports I find that there are three libraries left.

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/libdevkit.a
/usr/local/lib/libkld.a
/usr/local/lib/libredo_prebinding.a
```

I already did some googling and see that other people get some of these same messages.

All these files seem to have a rather old dates

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 ramberg  staff  640412 Jul 14  2002 /usr/local/lib/libdevkit.a
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 ramberg  staff  1465960 Nov 20  2002 /usr/local/lib/libkld.a
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 ramberg  staff  1054648 Nov 20  2002 /usr/local/lib/libredo_prebinding.a
```

Is there anyway to determine where these libs may have come from and if they are safe to remove  ?

I am currently running mountain lion; but I have steadily upgraded OS since I got this Mac in 2010

I would like to have /usr/local totally under brew control; but I don't want to disable a package that I may have forgotten about.